# Android - PullToRefresh ListView always empty

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to implement [chrisbanes's Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) in my app.
But so far all I'm getting is an empty view.
If I change the ListView to an Android widget it works fine, if I use PullToRefreshListView the list shows up empty.
I'm using a custom ListAdapter.

Here's the XML part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_jogos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" >
    </com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code in the activity (it's being called, at least according to the debug information):

```
private void constroiLista(ArrayList<Jogo> lista)
{
    PullToRefreshListView lv = (PullToRefreshListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_jogos);
    if(lv != null && lista != null)
    {
        lv.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, lista));
        lv.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView)
            {
                (dnt = new DownloadJogosTask()).execute();
            }
        });
        // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
        lv.onRefreshComplete();
    }
}
```

And if it makes a difference the layout containing this listview is being inflated into a base one:

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_base_layout)).addView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.lista_jogos, null));
```

Is there any known bugs associated with this library? I searched around but haven't found anything similar. Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying what was suggested by Tarek, I noticed that the PullToRefreshListView's height was always 0.

If I use `setContentView` to set the layout instead of inflating it into another.. it works or if I set a fixed height `new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1000)`

After messing around I ended up adding this block of code on my `customOnCreate` method to make it work:

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_base_layout)).addView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.lista_jogos, null));
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_jogos);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)ll.getLayoutParams();
params.weight = 1;
ll.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your `(dnt = new DownloadJogosTask()).execute()` will download `Jogo`s and add them to `lista`.

If this is your scenario than try the following:

```
ListAdapter la = null; //make your ListAdapter global in your activity
PullToRefreshListView lv = null; //also the same for the list

private void constroiLista(ArrayList<Jogo> lista) {

    lv = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_jogos);
    la = new ListAdapter(this, lista); // initialize the list adapter
    lv.setAdapter(la);

    lv.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
            if (lv != null && lista != null) { //if null do not execute the task
                (dnt = new DownloadJogosTask()).execute();
            }
        }
    });
    // here is not when the list refresh is complete so remove this line

}
```

in the `onPostExecute` of `DownloadJogosTask` you call `la.notifyDataSetChanged();` to notify the adapter that you have new values added to your `lista` and then call `lv.onRefreshComplete();` which only hides the loading animation.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    la.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.onRefreshComplete();
}
```

hope this help.

Comment: It didn't work, but helped me notice that the PullToRefreshListView's height was always 0.
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace match_parent from wrap_content in PullToRefreshListView

```
 <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_jogos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" <= Replace This Attribute
        android:divider="@null" >
    </com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView>
```